# how can i insert a google sites into jupyter notebook with R

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

Is there any command to insert a sites.google into a notebook with IRkernel? I can find just the method to get the visible hyperlink with markdown cell:

```
IRdisplay::display_html("< a href="https://sites.google.com/something" 
 target=_blank>Something< /a>")
```

but i can't find the command to get the web pages directly into the notebook:

```
IRdisplay::display_html('< iframe src="https://sites.google.com/something" 
 width="400", height="400">< /iframe>
```

in this second case i got only a blank pages with no possibility to get the original web pages.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make things complicated.  The following should make it happen.

```
> display_html('<iframe src="="https://sites.google.com/something/"  align="center" width="450" height="225" frameBorder="0"></iframe>')
```

The width and height can be proportionately adjusted to product the desired result.